# What's the problem with this implementation of selection sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, selection, quicksort

I am learning selection sort. 
I am getting the correct output for some values, but not for all the values, don't know why??

Please find below code snippet:

```js
function selectionSortRecursion(arr,p){
    if( arr.length === 1){
        return p;
    }
    min=arr[0];
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i]<min){
            min = arr[i];
            var minIdx=i;
        }
    }
    temp=arr[0];
    arr[0]=arr[minIdx];
    arr[minIdx]=temp;
    p.push(arr.shift());

    return selectionSortRecursion(arr,p);
}
console.log(selectionSortRecursion([2,3,5,-3,20,0,2,6,-23],[]));
```

Comment: Have you debugged it yet? t were your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `minIdx` is not declared unless the body of the `if` statement inside the loop is executed. If the minimum element is at index 0, then `arr[i] < min` is never true and `minIdx` is undefined.

To solve it, write `var minIdx = 0;` before the loop, since `min` is initialised as the value at index 0. A couple of your other variables should be declared with `var`, too:

```js
function selectionSortRecursion(arr, p) {
    if(arr.length === 0) {
        return p;
    }
    var min = arr[0];
    var minIdx = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
            minIdx = i;
        }
    }
    var temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[minIdx];
    arr[minIdx] = temp;
    p.push(arr.shift());

    return selectionSortRecursion(arr, p);
}
```

Note that I've also changed the loop variable `i` to start at 1, since there's no need to compare index 0 with itself; and the base case of the recursion should be when `arr.length` is 0, not 1, to avoid losing the last element.